# Why doesn't haproxy tcp check work when proxying via itself

Tags: haproxy

In order to get around healthchecks where SNI is required while using TCP I have the following which kind of works

```
listen website
  bind :10003
  mode tcp

  server website_proxy_aws localhost:14001  check fall 3 rise 2
  server website_proxy_dc  localhost:14002  check fall 3 rise 2

listen website_proxy_aws
  bind :14001
  mode tcp
  option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ website-lb.domain.com
  server website_proxy_svc_aws internal-alb.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com:80 check sni req.hdr(Host) verify none fall 3 rise 2 weight 2

listen website_proxy_do
  bind :14002
  mode tcp
  option httpchk HEAD  / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ website-lb.domain.com
  server ivendiwebsite_proxy_svc_dc do-website-lb.domain.com:443 check ssl sni req.hdr(Host) verify none  fall 3 rise 2 weight 2
```

Now if `website_proxy_do` is down it appears red for the `website_proxy_do` listener in the stats page.
But the `website` listener appears green for both.

I imagine there's a simple explanation to what I'm doing wrong here.

*(I'm aware in this example I could use one listen as the host is the same across both I'm just interested in why the website listener is supposedly doing a tcp check but failing to acknowledge that the down site is down)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood what you are looking at. Before I answer, I would like to add how I replicated the problem so that it is easy to say that we are on the same page.

These are my HAProxy listeners replicated similar to what you did.

```
listen port_33306
   bind :33306
   mode tcp
   server local-tunnel localhost:23306 check


listen port_23306
   bind :23306
   mode tcp
   server mysql-tunnel localhost:13306 check
```

I tunnelled a MySQL running on Aurora using `socat` on port 13306, this would make it very easy to understand what's the problem would be.

So here is what it looks like

```
localhost:33306 => localhost:23306 => localhost:13306 => myaurora.aws-aurora-blah-blah.com:3306
```

Right now, here is what my `netstat` looks like

```
robot@proxy:~$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name                    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:13306           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3465/socat          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23306           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33306           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

And this is what my `haproxy?stats` page look like.

[image]

Now, I am taking down that `socat` tunnel of tcp port `13306` to Aurora, so like you said it will disrupt the flow and show listener `port_23306` as red on my `haproxy?stats` page because port `13306` is no longer exists.

[image]

So, until here we are having the similar outputs and now the question is why is listener `port_33306` still green while the `port_23306` is failing checks.

Right now this what my `netstat` looks like.

```
robot@proxy:~$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name                    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23306           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33306           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

As you can see, the tunnel `socat` for port `13306` doesn't exist as I killed the process, and the listener is checking for `localhost:13306`. Even though the connection doesn't exist, HAProxy kept the port binding open leaving port `23306` for comms if I start the tunnel it will be obviously back to green without restarting my HAProxy.

Due to this, `23306` is open and the listener in `port_33306` which bind the port `33306` to `localhost:23306` checks for `23306` only and doesn't do any deeper checks down the tree if `23306` is connected to some process or not.

Hence, we are able to see listener `port_33306` still green as it checks for port `23306` and while listener `port_23306` is red, as binding `23306` is open and ready to get connected to something but the check is done on port `13306` which is not open, so health checks are passing for port `23306` but not for `13306`.

It's difficult to explain in exact terms and everything, but I tried.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah right so if I have two listeners X and Y and a balancer over the two called A; if the health checks fail on Y the port remains open so A doesn't know that Y is down. Makes sense from a haproxy view (annoying as hell from an expectation of a tcp check working) Thanks

Comment: This works but, you are wasting resources and increasing latency.

Comment: Thanks, question is about why it doesn't show not about how to implement. Yeah I agree with the network latency, think about a complex system with 100 VMs in a cluster and only 1 has public IP allocated, and allowing comms between two different clusters. Would you risk opening the port 3306 to 0.0.0.0/0 or willing to open it just to some server who's IP you know.